# Average similar strings values

Tags: sql, mysqli

I've created an SQL query that combines a few tables into the following structure:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ID      NAME     Test         Score   Date Completed   Display Name
2      User 1   Test Foobar 1  80       1528884606      Jakub Salt
2      User 1   Test Foobar 2  64       1528884606      Jakub Salt
2      User 1   Test Momo 1    70       1528884606      Jakub Salt
2      User 1   Test Momo 2    45       1528884606      Jakub Salt
2      User 1   Test Dodo      100      1528884606      Jakub Salt
3      User 2   Test Momo 1    77       1528884606      Brax Ramsey
3      User 2   Test Roro      98       1528884606      Brax Ramsey
3      User 2   Test Momo 2    25       1528884606      Brax Ramsey
3      User 2   Test Foobar 2  100      1528884606      Brax Ramsey
3      User 2   Test Foobar 1  84       1528884606      Brax Ramsey
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the query that I use to get this data:

```
SELECT
  ift_users.ID,
  ift_users.user_login,
  ift_posts.post_title,
  ift_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_value,
  ift_learndash_user_activity.activity_completed,
  ift_users.display_name
FROM ift_learndash_user_activity
  INNER JOIN ift_users
    ON ift_learndash_user_activity.user_id = ift_users.ID
  INNER JOIN ift_learndash_user_activity_meta
    ON ift_learndash_user_activity.activity_id = ift_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_id
  INNER JOIN ift_posts
    ON ift_learndash_user_activity.post_id = ift_posts.ID
  INNER JOIN ift_usermeta
    ON ift_users.ID = ift_usermeta.user_id
WHERE ift_learndash_user_activity.activity_type = 'quiz'
AND ift_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_key = 'percentage'
AND ift_usermeta.meta_key = 'learndash_group_users_9012'
AND ift_usermeta.meta_value = 9012
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a table that will give me an avarage of two tests that's under the same subject, for example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ID      NAME     Test         Score   Date Completed   Display Name
2      User 1   Test Foobar    72       1528884606      Jakub Salt
2      User 1   Test Momo      57.5     1528884606      Jakub Salt
2      User 1   Test Dodo      100      1528884606      Jakub Salt
3      User 2   Test Momo      51       1528884606      Brax Ramsey
3      User 2   Test Roro      98       1528884606      Brax Ramsey
3      User 2   Test Foobar    92       1528884606      Brax Ramsey
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not really sure how to achieve this kind of result so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `avg(score)` and a `group by` listing all the other columns you are showing by (your names in the quoted SQL do not agree with your sample data so can't be more specific). And "Date Completed" really doesn't make sense if you are averaging the scores.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using avg() aggregation and group by

```
SELECT
  ift_users.ID,
  ift_users.user_login,
  substr(ift_posts.post_title,1,length(ift_posts.post_title)-1),
  avg(ift_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_value) as score,
  ift_learndash_user_activity.activity_completed,
  ift_users.display_name
FROM ift_learndash_user_activity
  INNER JOIN ift_users
    ON ift_learndash_user_activity.user_id = ift_users.ID
  INNER JOIN ift_learndash_user_activity_meta
    ON ift_learndash_user_activity.activity_id = ift_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_id
  INNER JOIN ift_posts
    ON ift_learndash_user_activity.post_id = ift_posts.ID
  INNER JOIN ift_usermeta
    ON ift_users.ID = ift_usermeta.user_id
WHERE ift_learndash_user_activity.activity_type = 'quiz'
AND ift_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_key = 'percentage'
AND ift_usermeta.meta_key = 'learndash_group_users_9012'
AND ift_usermeta.meta_value = 9012
group by 
  ift_users.ID,
  ift_users.user_login,
  substr(ift_posts.post_title,1,length(ift_posts.post_title)-1),
  ift_learndash_user_activity.activity_completed,
  ift_users.display_name
```